# How to change the marker cluster icon image in angular google map?

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer, angular-google-maps

I have a list of markers in my angular google map. I'm able to create the clusters inside the map. But the issue is, instead of the blue cluster icon, I want to use my own icon.

This is my code:

```
        <section class="col-sm-9 mapContainer">
            <ui-gmap-google-map id="mapDiv" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
                <ui-gmap-markers fit="map.fitProperty" models="markers|filter:filterSite" coords="'self'" type="'cluster'" icon="'icon'">
                    <info-window></info-window>
                </ui-gmap-markers>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </section>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

`Angular Google Map` have 5 icons for markercluster. Such as `.../m1.png` -> `.../m5.png`. `m1.png` icon [here!](https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png)

You can update icons with config `clusterOptions="{imagePath: 'yourImagesPath/m'}"`.

Make sure `m1.png` -> `m5.png` exist in your images folder.

Your code should be:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map id="mapDiv" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
  <ui-gmap-markers fit="map.fitProperty" models="markers|filter:filterSite" coords="'self'" type="'cluster'" icon="'icon'" clusterOptions="{imagePath: 'yourImagesPath/m'}">
    <info-window></info-window>
  </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```